# Dependent rows leads to singular matrix (proof)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I prove the a matrix $A$ that dependent rows (non-trivial solutions to $A^T x=0$) singular(or non-invertible)?

Note: I don't want to use *determinants*.

Comment: As your question is currently written, it is hard to understand what you are asking for. Do you mean, if $A$ has linear dependent rows *i.e.* there exists a non-zero vector such that $A^\intercal x=0$, then $A$ is non-invertible"? Also, please show your work and tell us exactly where you get stuck.

Comment: What does singular mean to you?

Comment: @C.Falcon yes I meant non-invertible.

Comment: Then, try to prove the contrapositive of the claim. The result should be clear.

Comment: Note that $A$ is invertible **iff** $A^T$ is invertible. Hence $Ay=0$ has a non trivial solution, hence $Ay = A0 = 0$ and so $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: @copper.hat That is from the definition of invertible matrices(1st line of your comment).?

Comment: It depends on your definition. For example, you may say that $A$ is invertible **iff** there is some $B$ such that $AB=BA = I$, in which case it follows since $(v^T A^T )B^T = v^T (BA)^T = v^T = 0$.